# retrieve one column mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve some colums from mysql database. I want to retrieve the rows "tournament" and timeanddate". I have created this code to do that:

```
<?php
  include "admin/db.inc.php";//database connection
  $tournament_db ="SELECT tournament FROM sbc";
  $tournament = mysql_query($tournament_db) or die(mysql_error());
  $timeanddate_db ="SELECT timeanddate FROM sbc";
  $timeanddate = mysql_query($timeanddate_db) or die(mysql_error());
  ?>
```

For the output i have used:

```
<p><a href="turnering.php?id=6"><? echo mysql_result($tournament, 5)," (", mysql_result($timeanddate, 5),")"; ?></a></p>
            <p><a href="turnering.php?id=7"><? echo mysql_result($tournament, 6)," (", mysql_result($timeanddate, 6),")"; ?></a></p>
            <p><a href="turnering.php?id=8"><? echo mysql_result($tournament, 7)," (", mysql_result($timeanddate, 7),")"; ?></a></p>
            <p><a href="turnering.php?id=9"><? echo mysql_result($tournament, 8)," (", mysql_result($timeanddate, 8),")"; ?></a></p>
```

My question are: Are this the correct way to do it, or is another way to do it so that the loading time can be faster?

Comment: step 1 is using `mysqli_` instead of `mysql_` ... that deprecated syntax is hugely susceptible to attack.

Comment: `tournament` and `timeanddate` seem to be columns in your `sbc` table, not rows. It might be helpful for you to review some of the basic explanation of SQL.

Comment: You can do it in a single query: `SELECT tournament,timeanddate FROM sbc`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you r trying to do:

```html
$query = mysql_query("SELECT tournament, timeanddate FROM sbc") or die(mysql_error();
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query)
{

echo $row['tournament']." ".$row['timeanddate'];

}
```

OR

if the id is specified in the database and you want to pass it on the page you can try this

```html
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT id,tournament, timeanddate FROM sbc") or die(mysql_error();
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($query)
    {

    <p><a href="<?php turnering.php?id=echo $row[id]; ?>"><? echo $row['tournament'].",".$row['timeanddate']; ?></a></p>

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Highly inefficient, but it'll work.

Better way is to use a SINGLE query:

```
$sql = "SELECT tournament, timeanddate FROM sbc"
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo $row['tournment'];
   echo $row['timeanddate'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use deprecated mysql ,use pdo or mysqli
and use both columns in a single sql. Don't use mysql_result for large data because it can be slow;
use mysql_array and retrieve the data according to your requirement.